# Store multiple data of one column from all rows into one variable in PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like...

```
book_id.     room_no
1            101
1            201
1            301
2            201
```

I want to store all rooms having same `book_id =1` into one variable like `$room= 101,201,301`

What query I have to use

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Show your PHP code and efforts so far.

Comment: You can run a query with `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `GROUP BY book_id`, with the separator `,`. Though you're probably better off getting them as separate elements in an array rather than a single string.

Comment: $query= SELECT room_no FROM 'table' WHERE 'book_id'='1';

Comment: Great, then fetch that result and loop it - then you've got your rooms!

Comment: $query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(room_no)
FROM table WHERE book_id = 1 SEPARATOR ' , '  ";